# How to use Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls resources in (Uno 2.4)

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, uno-platform, winui

Readme after installation of Microsoft.UI.Xaml NuGet tells to put `<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />` into app resources.
But looks like this class does not exist in Uno.

[Here](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/34fbc75998593fc9f5018fb3775a0e2b2176d0d3/src/SamplesApp/SamplesApp.Shared/App.xaml.cs#L93) I see that it is added in code and with conditional compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class is not yet supported in Uno at this point. To add support for it on Windows only, you can add the following in your `App.xaml.cs`:

```cs
#if NETFX_CORE
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.XamlControlsResources());
#endif
```

Comment: Hello, Is it still not supported in uno 3.0?